# Фронтенд фреймворк — как добавлять view, а не перезаписывать?

Tags: роутер, angular2, фреймворк, frontend

Здравствуйте!
появилась задача, чтобы при нажатии на ссылки страница не обновлялась, а запрошенная информация появлялась блоками в main/main, точнее добавлялась к существующим.

нажали на определенную ссылку /heroes, в main/main  добавилась section
затем нажали на другую ссылку/кнопку, страница блоком добавилась к той секции (prepend или append)

Начал Изучать angular2, роутер такое сможет сделать?

или подскажите в каком фреймворке такую функцию можно легче всего сделать.

Comment: шлете запрос на сервер и вставляете ответ. можно и чистым JS, jQuery, та чем угодно....

Comment: Не сложный, а недописанный...

Comment: хотелось бы сохранить родной роутинг в фреймворке, чтобы в url писалось как надо

Comment: чтобы ЮРЛ писать посмотрите в сторону https://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/